# Does topical application of turmeric lighten skin color or make skin fairer?

Tags: medical-science, dermatology

There are [online herbal recipes](http://www.livestrong.com/article/355046-how-to-use-turmeric-to-lighten-skin/) which claim that turmeric helps to lighten skin color.

> The power of turmeric mixed with the natural bleaching power of lime juice will make for an effective whitener.

In fact, this claim is heavily exploited to run many brands of turmeric skin creams advertised as skin whiteners.

[A google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=turmeric%20whiten%20skin%20color&oq=turmeric%20whiten%20skin%20color&aqs=chrome..69i57.5411j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) reveals hundreds of websites with these claims

Is this scientifically validated with dermatological research studies?

Comment: Are you talking about eating the turmeric, or applying it to the skin? In the latter case I would certainly believe in its effectiveness as a skin yellowener :-)

Comment: @Nate: The referenced cite explains how to make a poultice and apply it to the skin.

Comment: skin whiteners are topical cream and hence I only meant only skin application @NateEldredge

Comment: Turns out this is pretty well studied, but I have no access to the review: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02864854

Comment: @Sklivvz yet found no research studies on human subjects for skin applications

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3453630/pdf/12291_2008_Article_BF02864854.pdf